# $n\textrm{ Hz}$ waveform sampled at $m\textrm{ Hz}$ per second

Tags: discrete-signals, python, continuous-signals, scipy

Here is an example of plotting a square wave given in [SciPy Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.square.html)

A $5\textrm{ Hz}$ waveform sampled at $500\textrm{ Hz}$ for 1 second:

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 500, endpoint=False)
plt.plot(t, signal.square(2 * np.pi * 5 * t))
plt.ylim(-2, 2)**strong text**
```

The documentation page states that

> The square wave has a period `2*pi`, has value +1 from 0 to `2*pi*duty`
>   and -1 from `2*pi*duty` to `2*pi`. duty must be in the interval [0,1].

1. Why in the example `5*t` is multipled by `2*np.pi`? 
   Doesn't the `signal.sqrt()` function 
   take care of multiplying the frequency `5*t` by `2*np.pi`?
2. What is the meaning of sampled at $500\textrm{ Hz}$ for second? I understand it is a $5\textrm{ Hz}$ waveform since `2*np.pi*5*t` takes care of creating $5\textrm{ Hz}$ wave. But I do not understand

> sampled at 500 Hz for 1 second

Comment: " Doesn't the signal.sqrt() function take care of multiplying the frequency 5*t by 2*np.pi?"  you mean signal.square(), not signal.sqrt() ?

Comment: @arpitjain: No, he means actual [square wave](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.square.html#scipy.signal.square).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The basic square wave function `signal.square()` has a period of 2*pi. Multiplying each time by 2*pi*f is a way of stretching the wave along the time axis to get a wave with a period of 1/f.
2. To understand what the sample rate refers to, look at the first line:

   ```
   t=np.linspace(0,1,500,endpoint=False)
   ```

   If you look at the [numpy documentation for this function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html), you'll see this creates a list of 500 evenly spaced numbers between 0 and 1. This is an array of times. When you then call the `signal.square()` function with this array, it returns an array of points on the square wave for each of those times. Thus you have sampled the square wave at 500Hz for 1 second.